# Any positive sequence $\omega_n \to 0$ can be bounded by a sequence $\{a_n\}$ such that $a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}- 2a_n \geq 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis

While self-studying I stumbled upon a problem, Exercise 1.4.1 from **Katznelson**'s *An introduction to Harmonic Analysis* asking that:

> Given a sequence $\{\omega_n\}$ of positive numbers such that $\omega_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, show that there exists a sequence $\{a_n\}$ which tends to $0$ at infinity satisfying $$a_{n-1}+a_{n+1}-2a_n \geq 0 \quad \text{and} \quad a_n \geq \omega_n\ \text{for all $n$.}$$

I've managed to find out that we can bound $\{\omega_n\}$ by a decreasing sequence converging to $0$, hence without loss of generality we may assume $\{\omega_n\}$ decreases to $0$.

So if we can somehow show that a sequence decreasing to $0$ can be bounded by a convex sequence which decreases to $0$ then we are done. However I am stuck right here, without any clue to proceed. Am I on the right track? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your start looks fine.  The next step is pretty simple conceptually: Define $a_1 = \omega_1, a_2=\omega_2$ and then $a_n = \max\{\omega_n, 2a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}\}$ for $n \geq 3$.  Now you just have to prove this has the right properties.